# RabbitMQ retrying messages without publishing from the consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

Can I retry a message N times and then send it to a dead queue without making ack and republishing the message from the consumer?

The only way I can think of is to use multiple queues with dlx setup which fills the next retry queue like this:

```
test ---> test.retries.1 ---> ... ---> test.retries.N ---> test.dead
```

Is this ok? I am not sure want I mean by ok. I've started playing with rabbitmq recently. Let's say is this a common setup? Are there any disadvantages?

Is there another way? Maybe a plugin that adds a counter to `basic.reject` and does the same thing?

---

Side note: I want to known this because I distrust the idea of having a consumer that will acknowledge a message (even though he cannot process it) and then publish it again. At the end you will end up with multiple liers that will publish a message and from time to time fetch it immediately before everyone else "just to be sure" and.. you'll make them remember.. (and they won't) [this also happens in the scenario with the multiple retry queues but at least the broker will control where the message is going not the consumer]

Comment: Acknowledging a message doesn't mean the consumer processed it. It simply means the consumer got the message.

Comment: From the tutorial: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html
"An ack(nowledgement) is sent back from the consumer to tell RabbitMQ that a particular message had been received, processed and that RabbitMQ is free to delete it.

If consumer dies without sending an ack, RabbitMQ will understand that a message wasn't processed fully and will redeliver it to another consumer. That way you can be sure that no message is lost, even if the workers occasionally die."

Comment: From the question it sounds like you are able to process the message, but fail to perform some other action based on the content of the processed message. In which case the broker has successfully performed its duty to deliver you a valid message and your consumer is simply not telling the broker that you've processed the message (even if some other unrelated action taken, based on the message content, failed). If that's the case, then the correct solution is to acknowledge the message and republish.

Comment: I think that you could create a consumer that has [read-only access](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) so.. the correct solution is to reject and to proceed with a scenario like the one that I've suggested in the question. (or of course you could leave the message to loop like crazy and maybe use ttl but the other scenario gives you more control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[basic.reject](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.reject) with requeue + [TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html)**

You have one queue and you requeue the message multiple times on failure and when the ttl expires you can setup a [dlx](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

**basic.reject with multiple queues**

On failure you always do `basic.reject without requeue` and use the dlx to send the message to the next retry queue:

```
test ---> test.retries.1 ---> ... ---> test.retries.N ---> test.z_dead
```

At the moment I am using this approach with only 1 retry queue and I have a special queue that receives certain messages from the dlx and sends me an email. (In my case a message is acknowledged in few hours)

**basic.reject with counting of the number of retries**

When you do `basic.reject without requeue` and use a dlx you can check `x-death` header added by the dlx to determine the number of retries.

Here is how it is done in [sneakers](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/blob/v1.0.4/lib/sneakers/handlers/maxretry.rb) - a ruby gem:

```
---> test (queue)
     |
     | test.retry (exchange)
     |
     ---> test.retry (queue - wait for some time with ttl)
          |
          | test.retry.requeue (exchange)
          |
          ---> test (queue)
```

At the end you count how many times you have passed through the test queue and when you exceed your retry count, you'll have to acknowledge the message (maybe after publishing it somewhere so you could be notified for the error).

Comment: @bilof, I have a queue `A`.  When I reject message from `A` it is not requeued. It is sended to `DLX`. Can I configure something like that:  Resend message from `DLX` to queue `A` each day at `14:00` ? Or maybe something like: control on single message level - try to resend message after one hour being in `DLX` ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Just add a cron that will move them from you dead queue to the A. Otherwise you can hack something with the per message ttl.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl

Comment: `per message ttl` does mean that each message which was resend from `A` to `DLX` will be resend to `A` after fixed time. And in case of again rejecting it come back to `DLX` and again after expiring ttl ... YEAH ?

Comment: @HaskellFun you can have 1. queue ttl - e.g. if a message is in the queue for more then an hour send it to DLX and you can have 2. per message ttl with e.g. normal queue, you (your app) should publish the message with your wanted ttl ps. read the docs. In case 1 the massage will loop forever obviously :) ps. this is why you need a condition in your app which will discard messages that have looped too many times. In case 2 the expiration header will be removed https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html